# What's the proper way of using Postgres connections in Node?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I was wondering if anyone can help me understand what the proper way of maintaining multiple connections to multiple postgres servers via https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres is.

Obviously when running a node server for long duration we want to make sure we keep everything clean with no leaks and so I am wondering what the proper pattern is.

Please remember that my Node server will need to connect to 7-8 Postgres servers.

https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres supports the idea of pools. I am wondering: do I just connect to all servers on initial Node server set up and maintain open connections and each function can ask for a pool when it needs to talk to a server?

In other words, am I supposed to call `pg.connect` every time I make a server query? (minus the `var pg` and `var connectionString` which could be global)

Can't I just have a single connection be on and ready?

```
var pg = require('pg');
var connectionString = "pg://brian:1234@localhost/postgres"
pg.connect(connectionString, function(err, client, done) {
    client.query('SELECT name FROM users WHERE email = $1', ['brian@example.com'], function(err, result) {
      assert.equal('brianc', result.rows[0].name);
      done();
    });
});
```

Code snippets are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It manages the pool so it is not going to be actually connecting and releasing database connections, that is the point of the pool. How would you use your "single" connection? Is this is in a web app, or are you writing (e.g.) a standalone data processor? Whether to get a new connection for every query or use one connection to make multiple queries would depend, but in many typical cases, there would be something like a 1:1 relationship between getting the connection and performing a query. I may not understand your question, although your edits did clarify things some.

Comment: thx for the reply!!!!!!! ... basically, its a web server that will be receiving thousands of users and will need to run queries against multiple (different) PG servers ... I guess this kind of sums it up: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Example  and so please explain to me, the pool will hold many connections to multiple servers and provide me with an already connected TCP socket to one of servers I need to run a query against? and if one does not exist in the pool, it will create one for me and append it to the pool for future queries or until I client.end() ? Yes?

Comment: You're welcome, and yes, you seem to understand it correctly. Also your sample code using the client for both the insert and select statements appears just fine. I was thinking you might have been asking if you needed to do a `pg.connect` for each query, period. What you're doing is fairly typical, which is using the one connection for each web request. However, you could also have one http request grab two separate connections (to the same DB) to pull in multiple data elements asynchronously.